# how to generate classification report using javascript

Tags: javascript, p5.js, tensorflow.js, ml5.js

I'm using ml5 for a classification problem and I'm applying KNN classifier. How do I get the accuracy and the classification report of the model?

Comment: Any joy with the answer below ?

Comment: Yes I understood how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the [documentation](https://learn.ml5js.org/#/reference/knn-classifier?id=classify) mentions this about `classify()`'s output:

> Object: It returns an object with a top classIndex and label, confidences mapping all class indices to their confidence, and confidencesByLabel mapping all classes' confidence by label.

Bellow there are examples as well, such as the [ml5/p5/KNNClassification_Video](https://editor.p5js.org/ml5/sketches/KNNClassification_Video) example.

If you print the `result` in `gotResults()` you'll see something like this:

```js
{
    "classIndex": 2,
    "label": "Scissor",
    "confidences": {
        "0": 0.3333333333333333,
        "1": 0,
        "2": 0.6666666666666666
    },
    "confidencesByLabel": {
        "Rock": 0.3333333333333333,
        "Paper": 0,
        "Scissor": 0.6666666666666666
    }
}
```

- `classIndex` will be the index of the top class
- `label` is the string associated with that class
- `confidences` returns object where the key is the class index and the value is the confidence (as a normalised value (e.g. 0.0 = 0%, 0.5 = 50%, 1.0 = 100%, etc.)
- `confidencesByLabel` provides the same confidence values as above, but instead of the class indices the keys are the class labels.

In short, once you call `classify()`, in the result handler, you're after `result.confidences` or `result.confidencesByLabel` depending on your application.